# Post-build Vue application in Visual Studio gives a "The command npm run build exited with code 1"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I am building a Vue app in visual studio and after running the build, I am left with the error: `The command npm run build exited with code 1`. I noticed it happening in the Post-build of my Vue App with the following line of code:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)"/>
```

this is my entire post build script:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEventDependsOn></PostBuildEventDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target
  Name="PostBuildEvent"
  Condition="'$(PostBuildEvent)' != '' and ('$(RunPostBuildEvent)' != 'OnOutputUpdated' or '$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)' != '$(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)')"
  DependsOnTargets="$(PostBuildEventDependsOn)">

<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)"/>
```

I expect a package javascript file to be put in my 'dist' folder of the Vue app. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply had to run VS as administrator.